# Scala list with stackable modifications example

Tags: scala

I have read the following example on stackable modifications in scala: https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/traits.html#12.5

We have an abstract IntQueue whose put method is implemented in BasicQueue. BasicQueue gets modified by some traits that should modify the behavior of put. I don't understand why this works. If I understand linearization correctly, then BasicQueue is the first element in the linearization, therefore queue.put should call BasicQueue.put. I think that the implementation of BasicQueue.put should be in IntQueue.put which is the last method to call since IntQueue is the last element in the linearization. Then of course put shouldn't be implemented in BasicQueue.

Is my argumentation correct or where am I wrong.

ps: I don't have access to a computer with scala at the moment, otherwise I would try it out.

Comment: In `new BasicIntQueue with Doubling` `Doubling` comes first, then `BasicIntQueue`, then `IntQueue`.

Comment: Thanks so far! In the article (under 12.6, see https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/traits.html#12.6) the linearization of scala is explained. In this example the class Cat is the first one in the linearization and the rightmost trait is second. Is this wrong or what is the difference?

Comment: Yes, but `new BasicIntQueue with Doubling` is basically short for `{class AnonymousClass extends BasicIntQueue with Doubling; new AnonymousClass}`.